# How to bind the json data to dropdownlist in Asp.MVC5?

Tags: c#, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

Hi i have one field called Employee. It is Dropdown. I want to bind the data from db to dropdown using ajax. 
I tried my level best but its not binding with dropdown correctly. Then one more doubt is have to use any general plugins to bind the data to dropdown list using ajax??

**My Model Code(VisitorsViewModel)**

```
  public Nullable<System.Guid> EmployeeID { get; set; }
```

**My Controller Code**

```
  public JsonResult GetEmployee()
    {
        var objEmployeelist = (from e in db.Employees  select e).ToList();
        return Json(objEmployeelist,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

**My View**

```
  @Html.Label("Employee Name")
  @Html.DropDownListFor(model =>model.EmployeeID, new SelectList(string.Empty,"Value","Text"),"Select", new{@class="form-control"})
```

**My Jquery**

```
$(function () {
    debugger
   $.ajax(
           '@Url.Action("GetEmployee", "NextFollowUp", new { Area = "Sales" })', {
           type: "GET",
           datatype: "Json",
           success: function (data) {
               debugger;
               $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                   $('#EmployeeID').append('<option value ="' + value.EmployeeID + '">' + value.DisplayName + '</option>');
               });
           }
      });
```

});

Comment: Unclear what your asking. Are you saying the options are not being rendered? And why are you using ajax to populate the options?

Comment: Actually stephen i know this option only to bind data to dropdown.Then after binding the data what ever value i have  select in dropdown  that value again i want to pass it to cottroller  for another operation

Comment: But why are you using ajax instead of populating a `SelectList` in the controller and passing it to the view? And you still have not explained what your problem is.

Comment: @StephenMuecke generally i want to bind the data from database to dropdown . I know 2 methods one is using ajax and another is using viewbag but using viewbag is not correct way to bind

Comment: @StephenMuecke I want to bind the data from database to dropdown list

Comment: @StephenMuecke i try to use ajax to bind the data from db to dropdwonlist because I know 2 methods one is using ajax and another is using viewbag but using viewbag is not correct way to bind

Comment: 1. As Stephen said, you could set the list in ViewBag in your action which renders this page and then do a  new SelectList(ViewBag.EmployeeList,...) 2. In case, you really need to have Ajax call for some reason,  then the above code looks good. Are you sure you are getting data in the success callback? Probably the structure is different, I mean, is data an array or the array is in data.d or in some other object?

Comment: I want to use ajax only why because i need to pass the value which i select in the dropdwon list again to controller for another function. Then i didnt get any data in success call back

Comment: @Developer have to use any plugin for this code??

Comment: No, you don't have to use any plugins. Could you just console.log(data) in success call back and post it here?

Comment: @Developer that means you ask me to add console.log(data) in success call back function()??

Comment: The is no reason at all to use ajax. Just pass the `SelectList` to the view (using a view model property). All you doing is losing strong typed model binding

Comment: @StephenMuecke i use that too and let you know

Comment: Stephen is right, if you don't wanna use ViewBag, the have a IEnumerable<Employees> in your view model or a lighter version of it as you just need key and value. Ajax call here is overhead.

Comment: ok i have a try and let you know

Comment: @Developer i got one issue in IEnumerable

Comment: public ActionResult FollowupIndex(VisitorsViewModel vvm)
        {
            vvm.EmployeeList = db.Employees.Where( x=>x.EmployeeID).Select(x => new SelectListItem()
                {
                    Value = x.EmployeeID.ToString(),
                    Text = x.DisplayName
                }).ToList();
         
            return View();
        }

Comment: @Developer here near X.EmployeeID iam  getting error

Comment: @Developer My Model        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> EmployeeList { get; set; }

Comment: You don't need that .Where condition.

Comment: ok i have a try and let you know

Comment: @Developer now there is no error in controller code

Comment: @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.EmployeeID, Model.EmployeeList, "Please select a Employee", new { @class = "form-control" })

Comment: But getting error check my view code is correct or not

Comment: Change your EmployeeID property to string; because the selectitemlist value is of type string. It is throwing error as the model expected is of type string and not of type Guid?

Comment: @Developer can you give sample one because first time i am using this so i dont have much aware about this

Comment: Okay..give me few minutes...

Comment: @Developer i will wait

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121995/discussion-between-susan-and-developer).

Comment: @Susan I have shared the code as answer below. Make comments in that if you need any help.

Comment: @Developer I have a check and let you know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a collection of Employees to your ViewModel or to Viewbag and then bind the collection to Dropdown. As per our discussions, you would like to go with adding a collection in ViewModel, there you go:

ViewModel

```
public class VisitorsViewModel
{
    public string EmployeeId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Employee> Employees
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

//There might be other properties as well in this class
public class Employee
{
    public Guid? EmployeeId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string DisplayName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

View:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model =>model.EmployeeId, new SelectList(Model.Employees,"EmployeeId","DisplayName"),"Select", new{@class="form-control"})
```

I have created a fiddle here - https://dotnetfiddle.net/zC3UR6

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to easily modify the following to use Ajax instead of Razor.

Please modify to your taste.

```
 <select name="ddlX" id=""ddlX">
    @foreach (var item in model)
                        {
 <option value="@item.EmployeeID" selected="selected">@item.EmployeeName</option>
}
   </select>
```

Then on the server side you can determine how many items you're looping through.

```
 for (int i = cursor; i < endNumber; i++)
            {
                string ddlID = "ddlX";
                var selectedDDLitem = Request.Form[ddlX];
 }
```

This also works for paged lists.

If you like I could do some html and css stuff to show how to use a div to place the returned html into. I'm not sure if you're asking how to populate a div or how to loop through the data correctly.

The reason I've answered it this way is because it also works on MVC6.